# Performance issue with Firefox on Highcharts and Highstocks

Tags: performance, firefox, highcharts

*This question is mainly FOA of the [Highcharts support team who said they would keep an eye on StackOverflow](http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=7673), but if you feel like answering, feel free.*

I am having performance issues with Firefox. Here is my configuration:

```
Firefox: 19.0.2  
OS: ubuntu 12.04 (x64)
```

The issue is that when dragging the mouse over a line, the animation (display of tooltip, marker, crosshair...) lags. This happens on the [Highstock (1.2.5) demo with 52K points](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/data-grouping), but more worryingly it also happens on [a simple Highcharts (2.3.5) chart with less than 200 points](http://jsfiddle.net/gT6mK/2/). I don't have any problems with Chrome (25.0.1364.160).

**Could you provide some feedback on this performance problem (are you experiencing the same? is this affecting only Firefox? is this affecting only certain versions?, do you know/if a solution will be available?...) ?**

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this article? http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/48-loading-millions-of-points-in-highcharts

You can also try to disable shadow / animations and compare if this modifications have influence on performance.

Comment: Thanks but my problem seems specific to `Firefox`: as I said I'm having performance issues on a 200-point chart whereas `Chrome` can run the 52000-point demo just fine.

Comment: Has this been addressed at all?  This is a major blocker for us.  Try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whiletrue/s6BmC/9/) in different browsers.  Firefox cannot scroll roughly 1k points smoothly.

Comment: Which version of FF? Cause i run it in the newest version 27, and have no any problems with performance. Have you tries to increase turbothreshold http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold